# Call keypress event on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have below jquery code which is execute on keypress but I would like to execute same on button click. Please help me.

```
$('#itemselected').live('keypress', function() { 
      //some code which using $(this) also.
}
```

Comment: `$('#itemselected').click(function() {`

Comment: Do you expect something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/fho10tsq/1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myFunction = function(event){
   console.debug(event);
   //do your stuff here
};
    $('#itemselected').on('keypress', function(event) { 
      myFunction(event);
}
$('#itemselected').on('click', function(event) { 
      myFunction(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to trigger the keypress on click

```
$('button').click(function() {
$('#itemselected').trigger('keypress');
});
```

Comment: what exacly is not working, do you have errors in your console?

Comment: I don't get any error while running above code. Can see input as object in console.

Comment: I can give you my skype if we can talk ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add 'click' to the list of event types like so:

```
$('#itemselected').on('keypress click', function() { 
      //some code which using $(this) also.
});
```